# Setting up SoftAP on Windows 7 problem

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I'm setting it like this:

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyNet75 key=mysuperkey
>   keyUsage=persistent

and getting message that all is ok:

> The hosted network mode has been set to allow.  The SSID of the hosted
>   network has been successfully changed.  The user key passphrase of the
>   hosted network has been successfully changed.

However, I can't start it:

> netsh wlan start hostednetwork
>   The hosted network couldn't be started.
>   The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the
>   requested operation.

Any ideas what gone wrong?

UPD I was able to launch SoftAP under freshly installed Win7 inside VMWare, so I can assume my hardware is compatible. Any ideas, what can be wrong with my host OS?

Comment: Make sure your hardware actually supports it and you have the Windows 7-specific driver.

Comment: Well, setup command finished ok, so I assumed my hardware is ok. How I can check if hardware supports it? It named "Atheros 11G USB Adapter" in description.

Comment: The MS article ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) say you need a device with Windows 7 logo. Many Atheros chips supports AP mode, so you'll just have to make sure you have the latest driver from your vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when my wifi adapter was turned off. I turned the adapter back on without connecting to any wifi network.

> The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not in the 
>   correct **state** to perform the requested operation.

The error message does suggest that the resource is not in the correct "state" ie off.